# Override CSS Background Image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am not sure why I can't get an image to show up in the background of this site: http://backroadsbrewing.com/

I have tried using the !important; tag, uploading the photo into the Wordpress' library, and linking within the stylesheet to the URL.

Not sure if you're able to see the code of the site without me putting it up somewhere? If you need me to post it, please let me know.

Comment: show us the sample code with your problem.

Comment: Please, post at least the CSS declaration of the background-image.

Comment: I don't see where background is applied anywhere. can you post the code you are using to apply the background?

Comment: Yes there is not any CSS which will display the background image.

Comment: where's the css responsible to display bg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not linking the correct css, you are linking the editing link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://backroadsbrewing.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=style.css&theme=onesie">
```

If you open http://backroadsbrewing.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=style.css&theme=onesie in an inkognito window or after logging out, you get redirected to login page, which is wrong.

You need to link to your generated css file instead of some wp-admin/ url (which will never work).

The correct link would be in your case:

```
http://backroadsbrewing.com/wp-content/themes/onesie/style.css
```

Regards, Max

Additionally, you have added an obsolete semicolon:

```
background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/Tb3g7Fv.jpg"); !important;
# instead of
background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/Tb3g7Fv.jpg") !important;
```

And you should:

1. never link to external pictures (they can always change or being removed)
2. only link to pictures where you own rights to publish (or it can get really expensive, like a customer of me payed 900€ for a single picture he used for a couple of years.

Comment: Thanks, Max — we weren't going to use that as the final picture, just trying to get something to work. I have some CC 0 images that I'm planning on using, but I just needed something quick that I could test. I tried uploading the photo as well as just linking, trying to test everything. But yes, absolutely right; never good practice to link to an external photo that can change and absolutely agree on purchasing photos or using your own (not stealing :). Just testing right now and couldn't figure it out! Thanks; I'll give your solution a go.

Comment: Great to see that we are on the same page :) You might consider setting the "don't allow search indexing" which you can find under Settings > Privacy while playing around with non-bought images. If the solution provided by me fits to you, please press the checkmarx on the left of my answer to mark this question as solved.

Comment: Hey Max, still having troubles here. Any idea on how to just externally host a stylesheet so I can just link to it in the index page? Whenever I try to do it, the page ends up with a .html on the end because I am just uploading to the web (like Google Drive or Blogger <- archaic, I know ;). I'm just having a hard time getting the index page in Wordpress to link to an internal stylesheet, so I thought I'd just go ahead and host the stylesheet.css externally somewhere, but don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Hey, as web developer I never thought that anyone ever wants to host something on google drive or blogger :D why you're not just using an ftp client, connect to your server and upload it there where it belongs to (to your website)? FileZilla is your friend. Or you install one of the CSS plugins for wordpress which gives you ability to add custom css too, like that one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/